# Law of motion when initial condition is perturbed

Tags: stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

We know how to find the law of motion (Ito process) of the value function:
$$V_t(x)=E\Big{[}\int^{T}_te^{-r (s-t)}f(s,X_s)ds+e^{-r (T-t)}g(T, X_{T})|\mathcal{F}_t\Big{]}$$
such that
$$dX_t=\mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dB_t, \quad X_t =x$$
and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration generated by the brownian motions up to time t.
It is, using the martingale representation theorem: 
$$dV_t=rV_tdt-f(t,X_t)dt+\theta_tdB_t$$
For some square integrable process $\theta_t$.

However, in an application, I'm struggling to find the law of motion of the change in the value function when one perturbs the initial condition $x$ ie the law of motion of $W_t(x)=\dfrac{\partial V_t}{\partial x}$. Any hints or reference on how I could proceed to find it?

Comment: What do you mean by "law of motion"? What I see is the Feynman-Kac formula.

Comment: Thank you for asking, by law motion I mean how can I write it as an Ito process $dW_t=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t$. A differential equation satisfied by $W$ is also okay. Applying Feynman-Kac to $V_t$ is not exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: then *what* are you trying to do? Writing the stochastic differential for derivative? Something else?

Comment: Dear @zhoraster, I'm trying to write the stochastic differential for the derivative yes.